# number possible outcomes of an event

Tags: probability

i need to calculate possible number of outcomes with detail screens.
the detail are: we have 1 textbox in which there has to enter any number from 0 to 7. There are 13 categories of the outcomes but average of all outcomes should be equal to the number entered in the texbox.

for example : textbox : __enter a number from 1 to 7__(if 3)______.

categories 1:  1, 2, **3**, 4, 5, 6, 7
categories 2:  1, 2, 3, **4**, 5, 6, 7
  
categories 3:  1, **2**, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
categories 4:  1, 2, **3**, 4, 5, 6, 7
categories 5:  1, 2, **3**, 4, 5, 6, 7
categories 6:  1, 2, **3**, 4, 5, 6, 7
categories 7:  1, 2, **3**, 4, 5, 6, 7
categories 8:  1, 2, **3**, 4, 5, 6, 7
categories 9:  1, 2, **3**, 4, 5, 6, 7
categories 10: 1, 2, **3**, 4, 5, 6, 7
categories 11: 1, 2, **3**, 4, 5, 6, 7
categories 12: 1, 2, **3**, 4, 5, 6, 7
categories 13: 1, 2, **3**, 4, 5, 6, 7

the average shud be 3. This is one possibility i need number of possibilities with screens like this.

can any one help me out in this i guess this to be deal with some probability distributions.

Comment: The relationship between what the user types and the categories is not clear to me. Do you mean that when I type "3", one of the 13 categories will be randomly selected? And then what? What do the categories and the number they contain mean?

Comment: There is PERFORMANCE EVALUATION CALCULATOR in which
one text box of average rating of a employee in which we need to enter a number from 0 to 7.

Next will show the 13 categories which contains detail ratings in each category. it could be in between 0 to 7. and by taking average of all will give 3 rating.

I need all possible slides with different possible outcomes in each category but the average should be same as entered in the textbox.




Hope you got my point :)

Comment: This seems to be a combinatorics, not probability question, and I would recommend posting it on math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

As a Haskell list comprehension: (with only 3 parameters, but you get the point)

lists input = [ [a,b,c] | a <- [0..7],b <- [0..7],c <- [0..7], avg([a,b,c]) == input]

then you select any random list from this list of lists